# Adding content just to the landing page or a WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, hook

I want to add an image below the header of my landing page.  I've managed to do this with the code

```
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'add_image_after_header' );
function add_image_after_header() {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $upload_url = $upload_dir['url'];
    $banner_img = $upload_url . "/Pelican.jpg"; 
    echo ("<img id='banner_pic' src=$banner_img>");
}
```

But the image appears on every page of the site and I just want it to appear on the landing page.  Also, is  there a more generic "after_header" hook I can use instead of the genesis version?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your landing page is your home page, you can use [`is_home()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) to only add the image when the home page is shown.

```
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'add_image_after_header' );
function add_image_after_header() {
  if( is_home() ) {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $upload_url = $upload_dir['url'];
    $banner_img = $upload_url . "/Pelican.jpg"; 
    echo "<img id='banner_pic' src=$banner_img>";
  }
}
```

For the hook, I don't think you can find another one more generic than this one (for your needs).

The [**Visual Hook Guide**](http://genesistutorials.com/visual-hook-guide/) is great to see where you can hook on genesis.

**EDIT**

[`is_home()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) works great when your home page show your blog posts, but if it's a static page, you should use [`is_front_page()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) which will be true for either blog posts or static page.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you very much.